# Why useState variable gets undefined inside try catch statement in an asynchrone function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, react-hooks, try-catch

I create a hook that manages the state of a single object with fetch to api. This hook exposes function to interact with this object.

```
// the hook
const useMyHook = () => {
    const [myObject, setMyObject] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await fetchSomething();
        setMyObject(data);
      }
      fetchData();
    }, []);

    const updateMyObject = async () => {
        console.log(myObject);                // log : { ... }
        try {
            console.log(myObject);            // log : undefined
            // ...
        } catch(err) {
            // ...
        }
    };

    return {
        updateMyObject,
        myObject
    };
};
```

Then i use this hook inside a component and trigger `updateMyObject()` with a button.

```
// the component
const MyComponent = () => {
    const { myObject, updateMyObject } = useMyHook();

    return (
        <button onClick={updateMyObject}>
            Click me
        </button>
    );
};
```

How is this possible that before the try catch block the log is clean and inside the block i get `undefined` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly alright !! **There could be a problem in the `fetchSomething() method`**. Ideally, it should return data, but it's not doing the same job.

Here is a small example. You can give it a try.

```
 const fetchSomething = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
        ).then((res) => res.json());
        return response;
      };
```

Comment: I logged and the response is good the data is well set. There might be a side effect but i am blind of it :/ i will try your code and tell you what i’ve got once i get back from my break

Answer (score 0):

I think this gonna work

```js
 useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await fetchSomething();
        setMyObject(data);
      }
If(!myObject)
      fetchData();
    }, [myObject]);
```

Comment: No actually this will trigger an infinit loop if you look at the useEffect dependancies.

Comment: Yes but you add if
If (!myObject) fetchData()

Comment: In that case the fetch function will never be triggered as myObject is initialized to null :/

Comment: So, you don't initial the object or write if like that
`if(myObject===null)`